# Android emulator shuts down when accessing video solution (exoplayer)

Tags: android, android-emulator, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

After some troubleshooting with updating the video solution to Android API 30, I have finally ended up with the following Logcat error after having upgraded Exoplayer to 2.12.0 and imported guava:30.0-jre:

```
[OMX.android.goldfish.h264.decoder] setPortMode on output to DynamicANWBuffer failed w/ err -1010
E/FMQ: grantorIdx must be less than 3
E/FMQ: grantorIdx must be less than 3
E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Inappropriate ioctl for device
E/FMQ: grantorIdx must be less than 3
```

I have also replaced SimpleExoPlayerView with PlayerView as it caused Inflating class error as described in my previous thread here: [Inflating class error with Exoplayer 2.12.0 on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65075019/inflating-class-error-with-exoplayer-2-12-0-on-android)

Was just wondering if anyone here had a clue for this one. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I also receive Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD) every time I try to access the video solution. A colleague tried to replicate the error using Linux and it looked like it worked for him.

EDIT2: It looks like it is mainly due to qemu_system-x86-64.exe stops working, which is mainly a Windows-file, so I conclude with this being a bug in Windows rather than Android.

Comment: Have the same issue. (grantorIdx must be less than 3 / Inappropriate ioctl) Not with Exoplayer, but with simple approach: MediaExtractor >>> MediaCodec >>> AudioTrack